# CTRL-ALT-DEL for init 0?

Tags: debian, init

On On my Debian 7 system the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> is this line below and is by default init 6

```
ca:12345:ctrlaltdel:/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now
```

But I want to turn for init 0 and not init 6 when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>.

How can I change this?

Comment: Read the man page for the shutdown command, specifically the -r versus -h option.

Comment: @CameronNemo Where this mam page is?

Comment: just type in `man shutdown` in a terminal.

Comment: @CameronNemo Sorry, I don't understand what do you want to do?

Comment: Read this: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?shutdown+8. Then, adjust the options after /sbin/shutdown.

Comment: @CameronNemo Ok I have to put -h for init 0?

Comment: Yep. I just wanted to show you how to use man pages (accessible with the man command) to get information on your own.

Comment: @VitorMazuco if you've found the answer to your question, consider self-answering this question and accepting your answer.